# Windows Phone 8 App does erroneously think it is English with Submission, but it is just German

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization, submission

My WP8-App ist definitely only in GERMAN.

In the Application Settings the "Supported Cultures" show: The one and only language ist GERMAN. No other language is checked. When I submit the app to MS it claims that the App supports German AND English, hence I am forced to add the english descriptions as well as the whole UI in english, otherwise the submission is being rejected.

(I think, that this is the case since I used Controls from the WP8-Toolkit...?)

Why do the Application Settings not really apply when MS reads my XAP-File???
Thanks for tips...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the WMAppManifest.xml file go to the packaging section and check if the default language is not still set to English.

Answer (score 0):

You were right, MakanWG!
There was actually a difference:
- The *Project-Properties, Application-Tab, "Supported Cultures"* (where I was always looking) showed "English" unchecked.
- The *Packaging-Section of the WMAppManifest* however, had the English-Box checked.
(WTF... !!!)

I consider this to be a (almost) bug from Microsoft - why are there two differing settings for supported languages...?

Thanks!

Comment: The point is that you should manage the languages in the WMAppManifest and not anywhere else. Your application Setting should change accordingly, if I'm not mistaken, but not really sure about that.